# How can I fetch a web page in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to make it so I can make windows form in c# to connect to a web page that is a Perl script.

So, I have this Perl script and I have to pass it 1 argument. I want to make it something like that
" https://(ip-adress)/arg1='arg1'/ ". Is it possible? And this script to be activated through a c# windows form button.

Comment: You just need to make [an http request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0) to the url

Comment: Thanks! But I was also wondering if you know how I can make it in perl? btw, that perl script is inside a ubuntu server

Comment: By requesting the url, the web server will execute the perl script. If that is not what you mean, then I don't understand the question.

Comment: Ok, okay thanks for the explication, but could you please give me an example of how this is used to get a hang of it? I'm new to c# and I want to learn more. By the way, do you have any idea how I could make the url. Like should I install an apache server and how could I pass the args?

Comment: At a glance, [this looks like a reasonable example](https://zetcode.com/csharp/httpclient/) of how to make a request in c#.

Comment: And what kind of request should I make?

Comment: `var result = await client.GetAsync("the url with any query parameters goes here");`

Answer (score 1):

That the remote resource is a Perl script does not matter. Access the URL and get its response. You don't need to think about how the server decides to respond to you.

That is, request the URL in the same way that you would any other URL in whatever tool that you are using.

Comment: hey, thanks for helping, but I was wondeing if you know how I could turn the script off, because in the script i use ctrl + n, but how could i do that online?